# Getting the widget that triggered an Event?

Tags: python, events, widget, tkinter

In Tkinter, I have a multiple widgets bound to the left-mouse button. They all trigger the same event when clicked.

How do I recover which widget was clicked?

I want it so when say `Label2` was pressed, I'd be able to recover that `Label2` was the widget that was pressed within the event it triggered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
def f(event):
    caller = event.widget
```

Comment: This assumes that the widget provides `event`. In the very simple case of a button for example this is not the case (at least for clicking the button).

Answer (score 16):

You have a couple options. One way is to access the `widget` attribute of the event object. Another way is to pass an object reference in to your function. Here's an example that uses one of each.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def onClickA(event):
    print "you clicked on", event.widget
    event.widget.config(text="Thank you!")


def onClickB(event, obj):
    print "you clicked on", obj
    obj.config(text="Thank you!")

root = tk.Tk()
l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Click me")
l2 = tk.Label(root, text="No, click me!")
l1.pack()
l2.pack()

l1.bind("<1>", onClickA)
l2.bind("<1>", lambda event, obj=l2: onClickB(event, obj))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have a button inside a label, which is that button parent too. I used event.widget to delete that button as well as it's parent. How to do this? Cause now, it just delete the button, not it's parent too

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like all your widgets are sharing an event handler. This excerpt from the *[Tkinter 8.5 Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)* by John W. Shipman - NM Tech, may help.

> **[54.7. The extra arguments trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20190307071251id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html)**
>
> Sometimes you would like to pass other
>   arguments to a handler besides the
>   event.
>
> Here is an example. Suppose your
>   application has an array of ten
>   checkbuttons whose widgets are stored
>   in a list `self.cbList`, indexed by
>   the checkbutton number in `range(10)`.
>
> Suppose further that you want to write
>   one handler named `.__cbHandler` for
>   `<Button-1>` events in all ten of
>   these checkbuttons. The handler can
>   get the actual `Checkbutton` widget
>   that triggered it by referring to the
>   `.widget` attribute of the `Event`
>   object that gets passed in, but how
>   does it find out that checkbutton's
>   index in `self.cbList`?
>
> It would be nice to write our handler
>   with an extra argument for the
>   checkbutton number, something like
>   this:
>
> ```
>     def __cbHandler(self, event, cbNumber):
> ```
>
> But event handlers are passed only one
>   argument, the event. So we can't use
>   the function above because of a
>   mismatch in the number of arguments.
>
> Fortunately, Python's ability to
>   provide default values for function
>   arguments gives us a way out. Have a
>   look at this code:
>
> ```
>     def __createWidgets(self):
>         ...
>         self.cbList = []  # Create the checkbutton list
>         for i in range(10):
>             cb = Checkbutton(self, ...)
>             self.cbList.append(cb)
>             cb.grid(row=1, column=i)
>             def handler(event, self=self, i=i):  # [1]
>                 return self.__cbHandler(event, i)
>             cb.bind("<Button-1>", handler)
>         ...
>     def __cbHandler(self, event, cbNumber):
>         ...
> ```
>
> `[1]` These lines define a new function
>   `handler` that expects three
>   arguments. The first argument is the
>   `Event` object passed to all event
>   handlers, and the second and third
>   arguments will be set to their default
>   values?the extra arguments we need to
>   pass it.
>
> This technique can be extended to
>   supply any number of additional
>   arguments to handlers.

A slightly more concise way to do this, as @Bryan Oakley does for the second button in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300301/355230), is to define each handler function in-line with a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression, i.e.:

```
def __createWidgets(self):
    ...
    self.cbList = [] # Create the checkbutton list
    for i in range(10):
        cb = Checkbutton(self, ...)
        self.cbList.append(cb)
        cb.grid(row=1, column=i)
        cb.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, self=self, i=i:
                                self.__cbHandler(event, i))
    ...
def __cbHandler(self, event, cbNumber):
    ...
```